# Flask : Redirect after returning a Flask Response object

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a web app where I'm running a shell script and printing live output by returning Response object. Is there a way I can redirect to another page once the shell script is done running?

```
@app.route("/setup", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def setup():
    def inner():
        command = ["./test.bash", "exam"]
        proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
            yield line.rstrip() + '<br/>\n'
    return Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')
    # After this I want to redirect to another page say success.html
```

Or if there is a way, I can include a template within the Response object, I can include some buttons to navigate to the page I want to.

I also want to do something like:

```
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
    if line == "Success":
        # Redirect to success.html after returning Response object with script output
    else:
        # Redirect to error.html after returning Response object with script
```

output

Is this possible?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can return an HTML page OR redirect to another page. If you try doing both, the user will not be able to see the original HTML because of immediate redirection.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run a continuous script and get live output from it on the page?

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin: I am able to get live output from the script. But once the script runs I want to redirect to some page.

Comment: Maybe client-side (javascript) code will work better in this case? Like making an event listener or periodically checking if some output from the server has come, if yes - redirect by changing `location.href`

Answer (score 2):

`yield '<script>document.location.href="http://redirect.me"</script>'`

might work at the end... depending on if the browser is interpretting the streamed data or just dumping it. that said a better teqnique in general is to use something like celery for long running tasks and then use js to interogate the server to see if its done